# server does not understand jsonp

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, jsonp

I have uploaded jsonp file on server, jsonp file has some script which is being used in my php file.

it is working perfectly fine in local, but when it is uploaded on server, it says **Internal Server Error**

does anybody know how to deal with this.

some insights:

- local and live server are identical
- both php and Apache version are same

my jsonp file:

```
define({ "content" : "<script id=\"bq-campaign\" type=\"text/template\">\n    <form action=\"javascript:void(0)\">\n        <div class=\"bq-layout\">\n        <% if (_bqOptions.whitelabel === 'n') {%>\n          <div class=\"bq-progressbar\"><div class=\"bq-progress\"></div></div>\n        <%}%>\n        <div class=\"bq-header\"></div>\n\n        <div class=\"bq-fields-cnt\">\n            <div class=\"bq-fields\"></div>\n        </div>\n\n        <div class=\"bq-errors\"></div>\n\n        <div class=\"bq-controls\"></div>\n\n        <div class=\"bq-tcpa\"></div>\n        <div class=\"bq-disclaimer\"></div>\n\n        <div class=\"bq-footer\">\n            <div class=\"page-footer\">\n                <div class=\"page-pp-tc\">\n                    <a href=\"privacy.php\" target=\"_blank\">Privacy Policy</a> -\n                    <a href=\"privacy.php\" target=\"_blank\">Terms of Use</a>\n                </div>\n            </div>\n        </div>\n   </div>\n        <div id=\"bq-popup-container\"></div>\n    </form>\n</script>\n\n<script id=\"bq-header\" type=\"text/template\">\n    <% if (_bqOptions.whitelabel !== 'n') {%>\n      <div class=\"tabheader\"></div>\n    <%}%>\n\n    <h1><%= preFillStr(header.title) %></h1>\n    <p class=\"call-to-action\"> <%= preFillStr(header.subTitle) %></p>\n    <div class=\"first-line-divider\"></div>\n</script>\n"});
```

jsonp file is valid, and working fine in local, so i assume server does not support mime type so if anybody has any workaround or suggestion please let me know.

Thanks
Amit

Comment: if you dont know answer atleast dont mark it for closer.

Comment: Could you add some code exmple and the stack trace of the error you get? With your description it's just guessing.

Comment: @JavierFromMadrid its preety simple dear, however let me add the code here.